# htaccess for search query string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I have one search form like,

```
<form class="navbar-form header_search_form" role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_job_search_form" method="post">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="" class="header_search_field" placeholder="Search">
 <img src="images/search.png">
 </div>
 </form>
```

and .htaccess file like below

```
#Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/job/search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ $1/job_search.php?query=$2 [NC,L]
```

Jquery :

```
$(function() {

$('#header_job_search_form').validate({
    rules: {
        search: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        search: {
            required: "Please enter keyword."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var query = $.trim($("#search").val());
        query = query.replace(/ /g, "+");
        window.location.href = job_seeker_url+'job/search/'+query;
    }
});

});
```

My project path is **www/html/job**.
And search form is in **www/html/job/job-seeker** folder.

When i will search keyword like **php developer** then working fine but when am i trying keywork like **php & wordpress developer** so only **php** keyword search.

Answer (score 0):

**Special characters** are required to escape (use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method) to form a valid URI.

```
window.location.href = job_seeker_url+'job/search/'+ encodeURIComponent(query);
```